Merge array using sum
I am trying to merge/filter an array by shop name and it's status (group by shop & status), also need to sum it's rent_toaal, latefee_total, amount_total and finally count total_shops.
Required output:
[
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "paid",
    "rent_total": 200,
    "latefee_total": 2,
    "amount_total": 202,
    "total_shops": 2
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 300,
    "latefee_total": 3,
    "amount_total": 303,
    "total_shops": 3
  },
  {
    "shop": "Goushala road",
    "status": "paid",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101,
    "total_shops": 1
  },
  {
    "shop": "Goushala road",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 200,
    "latefee_total": 2,
    "amount_total": 201,
    "total_shops": 2
  },
  {
    "shop": "Shiv Pahad",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101,
    "total_shops": 1
  }
]

I tried this but it's just filtering by shop name:


var arr = [{
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "paid",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "paid",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Goushala road",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Goushala road",
    "status": "paid",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Goushala road",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 100
  },
  {
    "shop": "Shiv Pahad",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  }
]

var result = [];

res.forEach(function(a) {
  if (!this[a.area, a.status]) {
    this[a.area] = {
      area: a.area,
      status: a.status,
      rent_total: 0,
      latefee_total: 0,
      amount_total: 0
    };
    result.push(this[a.area]);
  } else {
    this[a.area].rent_total += a.rent_total;
    this[a.area].latefee_total += a.latefee_total;
    this[a.area].amount_total += a.amount_total;
  }
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




You should add the code you've attempted to your question so we can help with any problems you might have.

Protip: use let and const in 2024, not var. Also, arrays and other objects can be initialized with const. Properties of these objects can be changed without violating the constant principle.

You are missing taking both the shop name and the status into consideration when grouping the data and also add a total to keep track of the total number of shops


const arr = [
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "paid",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "paid",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Dumka Town",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Goushala road",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Goushala road",
    "status": "paid",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  },
  {
    "shop": "Goushala road",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 100
  },
  {
    "shop": "Shiv Pahad",
    "status": "pending",
    "rent_total": 100,
    "latefee_total": 1,
    "amount_total": 101
  }
]

let result = [];
arr.forEach(function (a) {
    let key = a.shop + '|' + a.status; // Combined shop name and status as key
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = { 
            shop: a.shop, 
            status: a.status, 
            rent_total: 0, 
            latefee_total: 0, 
            amount_total: 0,
            total_shops: 0  // Added total_shops field
        };
        result.push(this[key]);
    }
    this[key].rent_total += a.rent_total;
    this[key].latefee_total += a.latefee_total;
    this[key].amount_total += a.amount_total;
    this[key].total_shops++; // Increment total_shops here
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);




You may find it easier to create a dictionary using the shop/status values as keys...
{ 'Dumka Town-paid': {...}, 'Dumka Town-pending': {...} ...}

...and then you can update the objects associated with those keys on each iteration.

Perhaps: reduce over the array of data, build up a dictionary of new/updated objects using the shop/status values as keys, and then extract those objects into a new array with Object.values.


const data=[{shop:"Dumka Town",status:"paid",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:101},{shop:"Dumka Town",status:"paid",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:101},{shop:"Dumka Town",status:"pending",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:101},{shop:"Dumka Town",status:"pending",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:101},{shop:"Dumka Town",status:"pending",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:101},{shop:"Goushala road",status:"pending",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:101},{shop:"Goushala road",status:"paid",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:101},{shop:"Goushala road",status:"pending",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:100},{shop:"Shiv Pahad",status:"pending",rent_total:100,latefee_total:1,amount_total:101}];

// Initial object settings
const initialObj = {
  rent_total: 0,
  latefee_total: 0,
  amount_total: 0,
  shop_total: 0
};

// Using an empty object as the accumulator for each
// object in the array...
const dict = data.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Destructure its shop and status
  const { shop, status } = c;
  
  // Use that as an object key
  const key = `${shop}-${status}`;
  
  // If an object doesn't already exist as the value
  // of that key on the accumulator create one using
  // the current object, and the initial object settings
  acc[key] ??= { ...c, ...initialObj };
  
  // Then update the values using the object's
  // values
  acc[key].rent_total += c.rent_total;
  acc[key].latefee_total += c.latefee_total;
  acc[key].amount_total += c.amount_total;
  acc[key].shop_total += 1;
  
  // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
  return acc;
}, {});

// Our output from the reduce is an object containing
// a set of objects as its values, so we just need to
// extract those values into its own array:
console.log(Object.values(dict));



Additional documentation

Nullish Coalescing Assignment (??=)

Template string


